# Show alert after progress bar fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an assignment. The task is to show an alert message after the progress bar has fade out. The scenario is: 
(1)select sth from autocomplete bar
(2)select a date from calender
(3)after the date selected and pressed the "submit" button, a progress bar shows about 5 seconds then fade out. 
(4) After progress bar fade out, an alert message pop up.

I 've done the first 3 steps, any hints for the last step? Tks for your help in advance!

Ok, I 've got what you mean. The code is too much. I paste here part of it:

```
    <h2>Pick your gift!</h2>
    <h4>You can select bag, fruit, book, toy, game, dvd and wallet</h4>

    <div class="ui-widget">
       <label for="tags">Your gift: </label>
        <input id="tags"><br><br>
        And which day you would like it?<input type="text" id="datepicker">
       <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
    <br/><br/>

   <div id="P1" style="display:none" >

   <div id="progressbar"><div class="progress-label">Loading...</div></div>

  </div>

   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#submit").click(function(){
     $("#P1").show().delay(8000).fadeOut();

   });

    });
  </script>

  ok, here is the progress bar part
  $(function() {
  var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
   progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );

  progressbar.progressbar({
   value: false,
  change: function() {
     progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
    },
   complete: function() {
    progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
    }
     });
    function progress() {
     var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;

     progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 2 );

    if ( val < 99 ) {
    setTimeout( progress, 80 );
      }
      }

     setTimeout( progress, 8000 );
      });
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? (the code)

Comment: It's too much, I just paste half of it.

Comment: Can you show the code relating to what you have tried that is not working?

Answer (score 1):

progress bar fade out ?

if you has access to the value inside that progress bar ( like the number % ) , you can listen to it  , when it reaches to 100% , then you can show an alert !

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the jquery docs? http://api.jquery.com/hide/

There are better ways to do this, but this way is relatively clear.

*in my initial answer, I faded in the progbar over 5s... silly.*

**Try something like this**:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    var hideProg = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#progress-bar").fadeOut('slow', function() {
         alert('progbar faded');
      });
    }, 5000);
    $('#progress-bar').fadeIn('fast', function() {
      hideProg;        
    });
});
```

Comment: I deleted my comments, but tks. that helps

Comment: Awesome. So, did that answer your question?

Comment: kinds. It's just so funny that the progressbar disappeared so fast just it showed 1 second I can see you put show 5000, 5 second,but I have another one in front of it. see the code. I have to hide the progress bar before calender date selected.

Comment: < script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){
         $("#P1").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();

    });
  });
    $('#submit').on('click', function(e){
      $('#progressbar').show(5000,function(){
    $(this).hide("slow", function(){
        alert("the progress bar is hidden.");
    });
   });
});

 </script>

Comment: sorry... typed this code in a hurry... parts are foolish. @log check edits